# Helpers from twitter-login gem in User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth

I'm using [twitter-login](https://github.com/mislav/twitter-login) in my Rails app. It's a Rack app that gets mounted in routes.rb.

It provides a helper method called `twitter_client` which is an instance of OAuth::AccessToken. With OAuth::AccessToken, I can make calls to the Twitter api:

```
twitter_client.post('/statuses/update.xml', {'status' => 'test test test', 'Accept' => 'application/xml'})
```

I'm trying to tie this into a method in my `User` model, but run into an error because the session is not available inside the model class.

What's a good way to wrap `OAuth::AccessToken#post` into `User#tweet_something`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to be able to interact with twitter is the access token.

The simplest way would be to add two columns to the users table: access_token_key and access_token_secret and update them when User logs in with Twitter (in a before_filter). The access token is stored by twitter-login in session: https://github.com/mislav/twitter-login/blob/master/lib/twitter/login.rb#L141

If you have the access token in the user model, then you can OAuth::Consumer and OAuth::AccessToken the same way twitter-login does it, but without the need for the session: https://github.com/mislav/twitter-login/blob/master/lib/twitter/login.rb#L49.

This way you can interact with Twitter on behalf of your user not only from withing controllers, but also withing background jobs, rake tasks and whatnot.